# Merging node list based on some condition in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have following XML input and need output grouped by Orderid and type using xslt1.0.My XML is very huge with many child nodes and elements I am giving a snippet and sample .
**Input**

```
 <orderlist>
    <order>
        <id>100</id>
        <type>c</type>
        <value>345</value>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>101</id>
        <type>c</type>
        <value>300</value>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>100</id>
        <type>c</type>
        <value>900</value>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>100</id>
        <type>U</type>
        <value>345</value>
    </order>
</orderlist>

    OutPut
    --------------------------------------------


<groupedOrderList>
    <order>
        <id>100</id>
        <value>345</value>
        <value>900</value>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>101</id>
        <value>300</value>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>100</id>
        <value>345</value>
    </order>
</groupedOrderList>
```

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html